# Key component 'Id' not a declared property on type

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I am using the out-of-box `ApplicationUser`, but with a few additional properties:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser, IPayCaddyEntity
{
    ...

    // TODO Figure out how to config.
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string CellNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Then for 'mapping' I use the following base class for `EntityConfig` classes for nearly all entities:

```
abstract class EntityConfigBase<TEntity>: EntityTypeConfiguration<TEntity> where TEntity: class, IPayCaddyEntity
{
    protected EntityConfigBase()
    {
        HasKey(e => e.Id);
    }
}
```

where `IPayCaddyEntity` merely ensures an `Id` property on all entities:

```
public interface IPayCaddyEntity
{
    string Id { get; set; }
}
```

Now, getting closer to the problem at hand, the config for `ApplicationUser`:

```
class ApplicationUserConfig: EntityConfigBase<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationUserConfig()
    {
        Property(e => e.FullName).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(MaxNameLength);
        Property(e => e.CellNumber).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(20);
    }
}
```

I'm also using the out-of-box `IdentityDbContext`, with other app tables:

```
public class PayCaddyDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    ...

    public DbSet<AccountPayment> AccountPayments { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ApplicationUserConfig());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new AccountPaymentConfig());
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

When adding the `ApplicationUserConfig` is commented out, all works fine, but with it operational, when I try to log into the app, i.e. when it tries to access the users table, I get the following error:

> The key component 'Id' is not a declared property on type
>   'ApplicationUser'

Calling `base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder)` before my own code makes no visible difference.

Now it is a declared property on `IdentityUser<TKey, TLogin, TRole, TClaim>`, from which `ApplicationUser` ultimately derives. Normally inheritance isn't a problem, as all my other entities also get their `Id` property from a common base class:

```
public abstract class BaseEntity : IBaseEntity
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

public class AccountPayment : BaseEntity
{
    ...
}
```

I get no errors with any other entities (I have removed quite a few here for brevity), and the closest guess I can make is where `ApplicationUser` derives from only the interface `IBaseEntity`, and not from `BaseEntity`, which normally provides the `Id` property.

Is this the cause of the problem, or what is, and can I do anything to fix it except configure my own `ApplicationUser` properties directly in `OnModelCreating`?

Comment: Have you tried calling base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder); first? I know it shouldn't make a difference, but the Identity/EF coupling has caused me much grief.

Comment: I think I originally had it first and had to move it, but will try swapping again, thanks.

Comment: No, @SteveGreene, I have now tried that, and it seems to make no difference.

Comment: Calling base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder) does absolutely nothing.
According to [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.onmodelcreating(v=vs.113).aspx), `The default implementation of this method does nothing, but it can be overridden in a derived class such that the model can be further configured before it is locked down.`

Comment: @TimCooke It only does nothing in `DbContext` and derived classes. It does quite a bit in my context, derived from `IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>`.

Answer (score 0):

you must also override the Id in the `ApplicationUser` entity

```
public override string Id { get; set; }
```

I think this is because the way the Entityframework works they can not reach the `public virtual TKey Id { get; set; }` which located in the base `IdentityUser`

Answer (score 0):

How are you implementing the `IPayCaddyEntity` interface? I reproduced your problem, step by step, and I didn't get any errors. The first approach should work fine.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser, IPayCaddyEntity
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }

    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string CellNumber { get; set; }
    //from the IPayCaddyEntity
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ApplicationUserConfig());                
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```